# How to send request parameter from Express server to React application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I want to send these request headers to my react application:

```
app.get('/',function(req, res, next){

      req.user = req.headers["id"];
      next(null, req.user);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

To send anything to client you need to put it in `res`, rather than `req`.

Do `res.user = req.headers["id"];` instead of `req.user = req.headers["id"];`

**Edit**

`next()` is used to pass the response to next middleware function. If you want to send response back to client then you should use, `res.send` or `res.json`.

Like, `res.json({"userid": XYZ})`

[Read More](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json)

Comment: @SankalpChawla actually I didn't get what you are doing with `next(null, req.user)` is there any other middleware going to be called? or you simply are trying to send response back to client?

Comment: I tried next() but same result. No there is no middelware , I am trying to pass the data to frontend.